# How to stop IFTTT adding single quote to Google spreadsheets formula

Tags: google-sheets-api, ifttt, google-sheets-query

I have an IFTTT applet that adds formulas into a Google spreadsheet. A few days ago, it started prepending single quotes to the cells, making them text cells and rendering them useless for my calculations. Has anyone observed this behaviour, too, and more importantly, how can I fix it?

Kind regards,
M

Comment: Just realized its doing the same here. Was ok yesterday.

Comment: Ping IFTTT on Twitter or email their support? I'm not sure what people on StackOverflow can do about that.

Comment: Yeah, I just figured that the Stackoverflow community could help if there had been a blunder on my side (e.g. like the spreadsheet requiring to be preformatted and the applet now exceeding the prepared range etc...). As it turns out, though, IFTTT had an issue and have supposedly fixed it.

Comment: Good to know they fixed it